# Proof that Jordan form with eigenvalues of 0 is nilpotent

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I can see that if I have a nxn matrix
Of Jordan form with eigenvalues of zero

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

How do I prove that $A^n = 0$

Thank you

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is easily calculated to be $X^3$, so by Cayley-Hamilton $A^3=0$.

Comment: Another term for this type of matrix is a "shift matrix" or "upper shift matrix".

Answer (score 3):

The linear map associated to such a matrix does the following to the standard basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$:

maps $e_n$ to $e_{n-1}$,

maps $e_{n-1}$ to $e_{n-2}$

...

maps $e_1$ to $0$.

Therefore, in $n$ steps all vectors of the basis are mapped to $0$.
Hence $A^nX=0$ for all vector $X$, hence $A^n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We may obtain the result by matrix multiplication:

$$A^1 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A^3 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, $A$ is nilpotent in 3.

Comment: I do like the simple route.